# WPF style problem with custom control and textbox-derived class

Tags: wpf, styles

I had the following situation:

- main application has app.xaml, which sets the `Style` for `TextBox` controls
- a custom control is implemented in a separate DLL, and uses several `TextBox` controls

The main application's `TextBox` `Style` is applied to the custom control's `TextBox` controls.  Cool!

My problem comes in because I need to use a class derived from `TextBox` in the custom control.  Now the main app's `TextBox` `Style` is no longer applied.  Can the custom control DLL have something like "app.xaml" where I can set the style for all my derived `TextBox` controls?  Or can the main application somehow set the `Style` for all `TextBox`-derived classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the BasedOn property of the custom TextBox style to the base style. Should automatically derive from whichever base style it inherits, in this case your application-level style.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}" BasedOn="{x:Type TextBox}">
```